# Sending Mail via Gmail Stopped

Tags: email

Our system was sending emails fine just until now.
I'm getting the following response. Can anyone help?

The error seems to be related to authentication, but password hasn't changed. Any advise would be appreciated.

```
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP a21sm25596087pfj.40 - gsmtp
EHLO rd00155d50d7af.domain
250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [137.117.9.62]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
AUTH LOGIN
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
c3VwcG9ydEBiaWxsaXZpbmcuY29t
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
amJqYjEyMzQ=
<> Please log in via your web browser and
534-5.7.14 then try again.
534-5.7.14  Learn more at
534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 a21sm25596087pfj.40 - gsmtp
534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbu3x
534-5.7.14 qqwDxkeiCBe55evYz8U5pozdCeuEWMf1echBlK4Ykmdot0LTgv1bDDQ_jnMs8GkFyw_ZAq
534-5.7.14 rmojkAJQAXfzRevQObN8MhH8hmMSCtMMmVJsuX5z805SazSchBKmytkfBbrjWalI6rTnix
534-5.7.14 z9_glL258Wjln_nWvFNhNevdanJ3CuUIsj9aRpExjUkygsDrQFixW-DeqU9pLzrsekK7uz
534-5.7.14 b8zCWUHGgSUYrxNb4M_kxWIEsuyk> Please log in via your web browser and
534-5.7.14 then try again.
534-5.7.14  Learn more at
534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 a21sm25596087pfj.40 - gsmtp
```

Comment: Did you go to the url it gave you to *learn more*? What did it tell you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google blocked your ability to send mail until you verify your account. Visit the url contained in the error message to unlock your account. i.e. https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbu3xqqwDxkeiCBe55evYz8U5pozdCeuEWMf1echBlK4Ykmdot0LTgv1bDDQ_jnMs8GkFyw_ZAqrmojkAJQAXfzRevQObN8MhH8hmMSCtMMmVJsuX5z805SazSchBKmytkfBbrjWalI6rTnixz9_glL258Wjln_nWvFNhNevdanJ3CuUIsj9aRpExjUkygsDrQFixW-DeqU9pLzrsekK7uzb8zCWUHGgSUYrxNb4M_kxWIEsuyk

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you need to allow less secure password or use App password. Alternatively, one can use Gmail OAuth. Google must have just changed its behavior.